# How to display html tags in from sql query in Spring view - JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'v a little problem with my Spring Boot application. I am fetching results from my MySQL and the plain text is for example:

```
<b>Hello World</b>
```

I am displaying it in the  view, and the output I am getting is:

```
<b>Hello World</b>
```

I want to get this:
**Hello World**

How can I display those html tags (`<b>`, `<a>`, `<font size>` etc.)?

Comment: How are you displaying the text in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JSP, the `<c:out value="${...}" />` tag automatically escapes the value so the characters `<`, `>`, `&`, `'`, and `"` will display correctly. This is as it should be, because without escaping your users may be vulnerable to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

There are two ways to insert HTML text without getting it escaped:

- Ask the tag to not escape: `<c:out value="${...}" escapeXml="false" />`
- Don't use the tag: `${...}`

I'd recommend the first option, because it clearly documents that the lack of escaping is intentional.

*Beware:* If that text comes from a user, a malicious user may inject client-side scripts to attack all your other users.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!